# QT C++ prevent Runtime Error when close app

Tags: c++, qt, runtime

I'm writing a QT application and everything is fine with building and working but when i close the app with a thread running, the app closes and shows a message:
[Runtime Error....].

The application output says:

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
example crashed.
```

how to solve that ?

Example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    example = new Thread(this);
    connect(example, SIGNAL(print_line(QString)), this, SLOT(print_line2(QString)), Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::print_line2(QString in)
{
    ui->textBrowser->append(in);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    example->start();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <Thread.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Thread *example;

public slots:
    void print_line2(QString in);

private slots:

    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**Thread.cpp**

```
#include "Thread.h"
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

Thread::Thread(QObject *parent):
    QThread(parent)
{

}

Thread::~QThread()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Thread::print(QString in)
{
    print_line(in);
}

void Thread::run()
{
    int count = 0;
    for(;;) {
        Sleep(100);
        count += 1;
        print(QString::number(count));
    }
}
```

**Thread.h**

```
#ifndef READINFO_H
#define READINFO_H
#include <QThread>

class Thread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
   explicit Thread(QObject *parent =0);
   void print(QString in);
   void run();

signals:

   void print_line(QString x);

};

#endif
```

[Ready example](https://mega.nz/#!WdRRRSJZ!RXomrjXTwcFeZ1r1EDOxI_Dkm_9-2BPxS45D-yuMKHs)

Comment: You need to run your application in a debugger, and examine your stack trace at the point of the error to pin down the cause. You can also try providing a minimal complete example that reproduces the issue if you get stuck (otherwise your question is unsalvageable).

Comment: it smells like a thread that you have not closed, but without a [mcve] we can not help you

Comment: I edited the original post and added one

Comment: Hello @eyllanesc

Comment: It would do well to minimize this code - think of putting it all in one file, perhaps also moving member functions into the class declaration bodies in Java style: the example will be reduced to 1/2-1/4 of the original size, and the boilerplate won't be distracting from the problem. It also helps to really remove anything irrelevant. In your case, you might check if removing the UI won't retain the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the thread is still in the running state when your application shuts down.

The code inside Thread::Run() contains an infinite loop -- there is no way for it to terminate by itself. You need to write your thread so that it will exit, or at the very least, you need to forcefully terminate the thread before your app closes.

To forcefully terminate, you could add two lines of code to the MainWindow destructor like so:

```
MainWindow::~MainWindow() 
{ 
    example->terminate(); 
    example->wait(); 
    (...)
}
```